# Helm Nested lists within range

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have the following content in `values.yaml` and `deployment.yaml`:

```
values.yaml:
===========
apps:
  test-app1:
    deploy: true
    containerports:
      - 8000
      - 8081
  test-app2:
    deploy: true
    containerports: 6000

deployment.yaml:
===============

{{- if .Values.apps }}
  {{- range $key, $value := .Values.apps }}
  {{- if  $value.deploy  }}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ $key }}
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ $key }}
  replicas: {{ $.Values.replicas | default 1 }}
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ $key }}
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: secret1
      containers:
        - image: {{ $.Values.image.repository }}/{{ $key }}:latest
          name: {{ $key }}
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
         ports:
            {{- range .Values.containerports }}
            - containerPort: {{ . | title | quote }}
              {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

How do I iterate if I have more than one container port within the range? With the above template, I am getting the error as:

```
<.Values.containerports>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.containerports
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: {{- range $key, $value := $value. containerports }}
          - containerPort: {{ . }}

Comment: above worked for me

Comment: Glad you found a solution by yourself. Please post it as an answer to your question, and accept it, so this question won't stay unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Change *values.yaml* so that both `containerports` are arrays

```yaml
apps:
  test-app1:
    deploy: true
    containerports:
    - 8000
    - 8081
  test-app2:
    deploy: true
    containerports:
    - 6000
```

otherwise Helm will throw an error

```text
range can't iterate over 6000
```

Then change `ports` block in *deployment.yaml* to

```yaml
        ports: 
        {{- range $key, $value := $value.containerports }}
        - containerPort: {{ . }}
        {{- end }}
```

You may also want to add a separator between resources, otherwise only one deployment will be created (*test-app2* in your case).

The entire *deployment.yaml* should like like this

```yaml
{{- if .Values.apps }}
  {{- range $key, $value := .Values.apps }}
  {{- if  $value.deploy  }}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ $key }}
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ $key }}
  replicas: {{ $.Values.replicas | default 1 }}
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ $key }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: {{ $.Values.image.repository }}/{{ $key }}:latest
        name: {{ $key }}
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports: 
        {{- range $key, $value := $value.containerports }}
        - containerPort: {{ . }}
        {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
---
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```