# Multiple path and multipe backend using single HELM ingress template template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to create a Helm template for my Ingress that should include 2 backends (frontend/backend) and allow for multiple paths within each service.
My current template looks like this:

```
  rules:
    - host: {{ $.Values.ingress.host}}
      http:
        paths:
         {{- range .Values.ingress.service }}
            {{- range .paths }}
            - path: {{ . }}
              pathType: Prefix   
              backend:
                service:
                  name: {{ name }}
                  port:
                    number: {{ .port }}
            {{- end }}        
         {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

And my values file looks like this:

```
    ingress:
  enabled: true 
  host: exemple.com
  service:
  - name: backend
    port: 88
    paths:
      - /api
      - /test
  - name: frontend
    port: 80 
    paths:
      - /
```

The desired result I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
    rules:
  - host: appli-test.kube.cloud-grdf.fr
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: backend
              port:
                number: 88
          path: /api
          pathType: Prefix
        - backend:
            service:
              name: backend
              port:
                number: 88
          path: /test
          pathType: Prefix
        - backend:
            service:
              name: frontend
              port:
                number: 80
          path: /
          pathType: Prefix
```

Any help or suggestions on how to achieve this result would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You're running 3 services in one pod?

Comment: no i run 1 service for each pod but my java application have many contexts api/test/health and i want to use them in my ingress

Comment: At a glance I think the issue with the template is the inner range is changing the context `.` so there is no `.name` or `.port` because `.` at that point refers to one of your paths. This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/71109162/1032785

Comment: I don't think this is the same case as me I have an iteration within an iteration which creates a problem for me that I receive an error like what name and port do not exist because they are in range paths can you explain to me what should I do please if you see that it is the same case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is that you have a different context in the second loop.

To fix that, you'll need to figure the index of the `service` to then reference it in the second loop from the root.

It goes like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: xyz
spec:
  ingressClassName: {{ .Values.ingress.className }}
  rules:
  - host: {{ $.Values.ingress.host}}
    http:
      paths:
        {{- range $index, $val := .Values.ingress.service }}
          {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ . }}
            pathType: Prefix   
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ (index $.Values.ingress.service $index).name }}
                port:
                  number: {{ (index $.Values.ingress.service $index).port }}
          {{- end }}        
        {{- end }}
```

The `$` references the root, so we start from there, then go down the path for service (`.Values.ingress.service`) and index it with the `(index <path> $index)` construct to then get the key we need.

Comment: thank you so much for your help it works perfectly as expected